# How to preview a local PDF in a Google Apps Script web app

Tags: google-apps-script, pdf, iframe

I am trying to preview a PDF that I select in a file picker. I understand why I can't preview it directly, but I thought if I uploaded it, encoded it in base64 and sent it back, it would display. Clearly, I'm not understanding some key detail. Here is my code.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
        function showFile() {
            var file = document.getElementById("pick").files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) {
              var content = reader.result;
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showBytes).loadPdfBytes(content);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        }

        function showBytes(bytes) {
          var data = "data:application/pdf;base64," + bytes;
          document.getElementById("preview").setAttribute("src", data);
        }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="file" id="pick" onchange="showFile()">
    <iframe type="appplication/pdf" id="preview" height="300" width="300"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Code.gs:

```
function doGet() {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index").setSandboxMode(
            HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function loadPdfBytes(content) {
  var encode = Utilities.base64Encode(content);
  return encode;
}
```

No error shows up in the console, but the iframe shows the frowny document and the message "This page has been blocked by Chrome."  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The iframe's src attribute is set in the function showBytes after the PDF has been encoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload the PDF file to your Google Drive and set the access to public. Then retrieve the URL of the Google Drive file and embed it in your webpage with the IFRAME tag.

```html
<iframe
  frameborder="0"
  scrolling="no"
  width="640"
  height="480"
  src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/<<FILE_ID>>/preview"
>
</iframe>
```

Ref: [Embed PDF with Google Drive](https://www.labnol.org/embed-pdf-200208)

Comment: That would work. However, the context for the question (which I didn't include) is that I am trying to see the content so that I can specify a useful name for the PDF, after which I will upload it to a Google Drive folder. Following your idea, I could use a temporary folder that I upload it to, then preview the file to allow the user to set the name, then upload the file with a new name to its final destination. Thanks!

Comment: You can use the Google Drive API with the ocr parameter set to true and save the PDf as a Google Docs file. You can then use Apps Script to determine the content of the document.